# Copy BLOB data MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently making an PHP script which is posting auctions for my marketplace. I use Ajax to post the $_POST variables, including: title, description, price, tags and SupportedOSes. The image as a blob in an external table called 'temp_images'.

The way I create the auction is by inserting a new auction into 'MarketDatas'. This is pretty straight forward for the most part. However; when I am trying to insert the BLOB it throws me an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax near
>   '?+Qi}'?m?Am............' at line 2

The PHP script for creating auctions looks following:

```
/*
    .... connect to database, etc!! I will spare you this and skip to the important part:
*/

// Get the posted variables
$title = $_POST["title"];
$descr = $_POST["description"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
$tagsx = $_POST["tags"];
$supOS = $_POST["SupportedOS"];

// Get our session variables
$Authenticated = ($_SESSION["LoggedIn"] == "1" ? true : false);
$User = $_SESSION["User"];
$Username = $_SESSION["username"];

// If we are authenticated, continue!
if ($Authenticated) {
    // Get our temporary image
    $ImgResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_images WHERE User='$Username'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($ImgResult) < 1) { die("NoImage"); }

    // Get image blob
    $image = mysql_result($ImgResult, 0, 'Image');

    // Delete image
    if (!mysql_query("DELETE FROM temp_images WHERE User='$Username'")) { die("Error deleting temp image from DB"); }

    // Post auction on market
    if (!mysql_query("INSERT INTO MarketDatas (Description, Price, Tags, Title, SupportedOS, image)
    VALUES ('$descr', '$price', '$tagsx', '$title', '$supOS', '$image')")) { echo "Error posting auction [48]: syntax[" . mysql_error() . "]"; }

}
```

As you can see, I try to store the BLOB as an string value. But it throws me an error.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Sincerely .. I don't see any INSERT/UPDATE in your code that contains `$image`

Comment: Your code is WIDE OPEN for SQL Injection!

Comment: My bad, I tried to solve the issue before :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `POST`:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["title"]);
$descr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["description"]);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["price"]);
$tagsx = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["tags"]);
$supOS = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["SupportedOS"]);
```

AND query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO MarketDatas (Description, Price, Tags, Title, SupportedOS, image)
VALUES ('".$descr."', '".$price."', '".$tagsx."', '".$title."', '".$supOS."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($image)."')")
```

Most likely your binary data contains `'` and breaks your INSERT:

```
version for the right syntax near '?+Qi}'?m?Am............'
________________________________________^
```